# how do i match each new element in matrix with all the rest elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, matrix

hi
i'm doing a score table matching all the teams with each other
**after adding new team it should be matched with all the rest teams**

Input: arr[] = {Team 1, Team 2}

Output:  (Team 1, Team 2)

Input: arr[] = {Team 1,Team 2, Team 3}

Output: (Team 1, Team 2), (Team 1, Team 3),  (Team 2,Team 3)

i found the solution with creating matrix of 2 elements rows but it's just adding new elements without matching it with all of the rest elements

```
let rows;
  if (teams.length >= 2) {
    rows = teams.reduce((rows, key, index) => {
      return (
        (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) &&
        rows
      );
    }, []);
  }
```

for now I have the following based on the matrix created but obviously it's not how i need it to work

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {teams.length > 1 &&
          rows.map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              {row.map((col, index) => (
                <td key={index}>{col.name}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is what **teams** object looks like:

```
teams([
      ...teams,
      {
        id: uid(),
        name: event.target.team_name.value,
        played: 0,
        win: 0,
        draw: 0,
        lost: 0,
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: Hi can you imrove your code examples. 

In the first part i dont even know what is code above `function HandleSubmit()` about and why is `map()` just console logging instead of actually maping?

Comment: Hi, I removed handlesubmit(), it's not relevant here. It was console logging to see if after adding a team the matrix was actually updated.

Comment: let the first code is adding elements part, right? So you want to compare wins and loses before adding and mutate the object - than add it?

Comment: no, with adding a new element I want it to be like this:  **Team 1** - nothing  **Team 2**  -  Matrix [[{Team 1} , {Team 2}]]  **Team 3**  -  Matrix [[{Team 1} , {Team 2}], [{Team 1} , {Team 3)}], [{Team 2} , {Team 3}]]    **Team 4**  -  Matrix [[{Team 1} , {Team 2}], [{Team 1} , {Team 3)}], [{Team 2} , {Team 3}], [{Team 1} , {Team 4}], [{Team 2} , {Team 4}], [{Team 3} , {Team 4}]]

Comment: like with adding new element to array create pairs of this element with other elements

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with matrices, you're forming "all permutations of size 2 without duplicates" given a set.